# Send emails with textarea value to all users from database with jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, database, email

I am trying to send an email to all users from database with the value from textarea. But I am doing something wrong here. I think the problem is somewhere with selecting the data from database, because if I add just one email address manually it works.

HTML

```
<textarea name="banner-text" id="banner-text" placeholder="Escrever…" ><?php echo $baner['banner']; ?></textarea>
<button type="submit" name="send-email" id="send-email" onClick="return false" >Notification</button>

$(function(){
     $("#send-email").click(function(){
        var n = $("#banner-text").val();
        $.ajax({
                 url: 'noti-per-email.php',
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: { baner_text:n },
                 success: function(data) { console.log(data) }
        });
    });
 });
```

PHP file

```
connection...

$banner = ($_POST['baner_text']);
$banner_message = str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $banner );

$sql_clients = "SELECT email FROM clients";
$result_clients = $conn->query($sql_clients);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_clients)){
            $emails = $row['email'] . ",";
        }

    $to      = $emails;
    $subject = '';

    mail($emails, $subject, $banner_message);
```

Comment: It looks like you keep overwriting your `$emails` variable. Rather try adding each value to an array.

Comment: How do you know "you're doing something wrong here"?  What's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not including extra emails in this part

```
$result_clients = $conn->query($sql_clients);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_clients)){
            $emails = $row['email'] . ",";
        }
```

The value is being overwritten. Instead of `$emails = ...`, use `$emails .= ...`

`.=` adds extra text to the string, while `=` overwrites it.